# How can I audit users and access attempts to SSH on my server?

Tags: server, security, ssh

I've had a few security problems with a server of mine, a few SSH users have been setting up fires aka giving problems.

I would like to:

- Track user logins and logouts
- Track activity of these SSH, in order to discover any malicious activity
- Prevent users from deleting logs

---

**I am not much of a sys admin and I am quite inexperienced in this matter, so any kind of advice would be very welcome and very helpful.** :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since we're talking about SSH servers, I will give you command line solutions.

- Track user logins and logouts. That's easy, the file `/var/log/auth.log` should have this information.
- Track activity of those users: If they are fairly innocent, you can check the file `.bash_history` in their home dir. You will see a list of the commands that they executed. The problem is of course that they can delete or edit this file.
- Prevent users from deleting logs: Users shouldn't be able to touch `auth.log`. In order to stop them from playing with `.bash_history` you need to do a couple of [tricks](http://www.pc-freak.net/blog/how-to-make-sure-your-linux-system-users-wont-hide-or-delete-their-bash_history-securing-bash_history-file/).
- What if the user manages to obtain root access? : You're screwed. Unless they make a mistake they will be able to hide all their footsteps.

Comment: Note that there is no way to prevent users from typing `unset HISTFILE` inside bash, and then their bash history won't be recorded.

Comment: @Gilles, please read the tricks link. They set HITSFILE as a readonly variable in .profile.

Comment: I thought you could unset a readonly variable in a non-restricted bash, but apparently not. This improves traceability a little since starting another shell (which won't read `~/.bash_history` or `~/.bashrc`) will show up in `$HISTFILE`. But that in itself could be perfectly legitimate (e.g. the user just wants to run `zsh`, or wants to set their own option in an alternate `bashrc`).

Comment: Yes. You can restrict him to bash or some other shell. After all security is just a race.

Comment: It's not true that "if user manages to obtain root access" they would be able to hide all steps. You can always use external server for audit, where all the steps would be recorded, including their becoming of root.

Answer (score 6):

**[DISCLAIMER]** I realize I am late to the party, but I would like to paste an answer that I gave [to another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181217/precautions-during-ssh/181260#181260), because I feel like it can offer some good insight to readers, and this question seems to be the go-to place for basic ssh info.

There was a similar problem that struck me after reading [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178016/how-to-keep-track-of-failed-ssh-log-in-attempts) question here on AskUbuntu and checking my VPS, only to see a bazillion of brute force attempts. That is when I decided to take action.

Now according to the question I linked to, if you would like to see failed login attempts on your machine over ssh (could be brute force attempts or anything), try typing this:

```
grep sshd.\*Failed /var/log/auth.log | less
```

If the output consists of multiple lines, that is many brute force attempts, especially if they have happened between short intervals, you might want to do the following pieces of action:

## Change the ssh configuration file

To do this, open the file located at **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** with your favourite editor, like this `vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

**1. Try to move ssh from port 22**:  Now locate the line that reads:

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 22
```

and comment out Port 22, and use anyone you might like. Example:

```
# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
# Port 22
Port 28934
```

**Please remember that ports below 1024 need special (root) permission.** I do not know how this could interfere with it, but I am just saying.

**2. Disable Root logins via ssh**: Since the root username is predictable and provides complete access to your system, providing unfettered access to this account over SSH is unwise. Locate the line reading **PermitRootLogin** and set it to **no**.

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

**3. Disable password authentication**: **Generate and use SSH keys** to log into your system. Without passwords enabled, attackers will need to guess (or steal) your SSH private key in order to gain access to your server. Something that is very very difficult. Proceed to find the line that reads **PasswordAuthentication** and set it to **no**

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

**!WARNING!** Before doing so, please consult this guide [over here](http://library.linode.com/security/basics) on how to set up certificate authentication.

**NOTE:** After you have made the changes use `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`. To connect to another port via ssh use: `ssh username@hostname.com -p <port_number>`.

## Setup a firewall

Please check out [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) on how to set up the extremely powerful and effective firewall, which is integrated into Linux, **IPTables**.

## Setup scripts to help you with security

One that I use personally and quickly comes to mind is [Fail2Ban](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/fail2ban/). Fail2ban will monitor your log files for failed login attempts. After an IP address has exceeded the maximum number of authentication attempts, it will be blocked at the network level and the event will be logged in `/var/log/fail2ban.log`. To install it: `sudo apt-get install fail2ban`

## Check command history via ssh

There is a linux command, named `history`, which allows you to see which commands have been input up until that point. Try typing `history` in a terminal to get to see all commands up to that point. It could help if you were **root**.

To **search for a particular command** try: `history | grep command-name`

To **list all commands after ssh**: `fc -l ssh`

You can also **edit commands using vi** (haven't tried it vim, though I assume it works as well): `fc -e vi`

You can also **delete the history**: `history -c`

**NOTE:** If you are not a fan of the command `history` there is also a file in your home directory (`cd ~`), called **.bash_history** (if you are using bash) that you can `cat` to see all that has been typed in the bash shell.

Comment: very nice answer. You should also look at the guide pointed by @radu in http://askubuntu.com/a/3906/59250

Answer (score 4):

A bit overkill, but you can see everything that is run on your system using the "process event connector":

http://www.outflux.net/blog/archives/2010/07/01/reporting-all-execs/

Answer (score 3):

1. Javier already answered this one: /var/log/auth.log
2. I have found a great article about this [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html).
3. If your users don't have access to root then your log files should be safe. You can try to build some custom rules in the sudoers file to restrict what your users can access and how. Also you can increase the log level for the sshd daemon.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the login itself there is no safe way to track/log users actions after they log in, assuming they have basic Linux knowledge they will be able to disable shell logging or simply running commands from other shells (e.g. python).

Instead you should be conservative about providing ssh access, do they really need it ? It's not very common to grant ssh access unless you are on the shell providing business.