# need to check if my ubuntu 14.10 has been hacked

Tags: 14.04, security, hacking

I have a Ubuntu 14.10 machine and I would like to check if my security is OK. 
I doubt that some one accessed my machine from internet and remotely controlled it. so what are the suitable tools I need to use to see if that really had happen and what are the logs related to this issue I can check for history ?

Comment: -1 This is far too vague, what makes you think you are "hacked" ?  this is unlikely, do you mean you have a virus, here's some reading on basic security, including vulnerability and how to improve your security https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity, but we need more info on your specific issue to help you, do you use a firewall or anti-virus, how/when/where were you "hacked"

Comment: WOW , all this down votes and close requests  for a question i see normal  that's strange anyhow i was just looking  for a guidance of a some linux tools or how to check my logs to check if my machine had been accessed from internet or by some people

Comment: I don't know why this got flanged, it shouldn't of, but I down voted because of a lack of detail, I told you what areas were lacking, don't take it personally, how can anyone tell if your computer was hacked without access to it or at least a good explanation of how you use it and what you mean by hacked, you say "i was just looking for a guidance of a some linux tools or how to check my logs" Your question in no way says this, please update it so we can help, and I will change my vote.

Comment: If by hacked you mean someone tried to get access to your pc remotely, this may be what you need http://askubuntu.com/questions/178016/how-do-i-keep-track-of-failed-ssh-log-in-attempts

Comment: hope the new edit make the question more clear

Answer (score 8):

It *is* a very vague question because Ubuntu Security is pretty good out of the box, and if I would have hacked your computer, you would not be able to actually check that you were hacked as I would have installed a rootkit, and the only way to get me out of your computer would be by restoring a back-up since before you were hacked…

The best way not to get hacked is to prevent it.

- Turn off all hardware you don't need in the BIOS (this includes: microphones & speakers as they have been shown in the past to be used as communication channels once the PC was hacked, printer ports, USB ports, WiFi, etc)
- Don't install Ubuntu in an Internet café, but at a secure Internet behind a NAT router.
- Install [RKHunter](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RKhunter) just after installing from DVD
- Black-list all hardware you don't need and that cannot be disabled in the BIOS
- [Secure your system](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Security)
- Always install all updates
- Don't let anyone physically touch your computer
- Use encrypted communications
- Install as little software as needed (and uninstall software you don't use any more)
- Don't install software known to track you (flash, silverlight)
- Use Firefox with the noscript and modify headers plugins
- Disable all cookies. Only allow cookies per site and only for the session.
- Make [system back-ups](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) so you can roll back to previous versions
- Use full disk encryption
- Only use the Ubuntu official repositories as [Linux isn't invulnerable](https://thepcspy.com/read/linux-isnt-invulnerable/)
- …

and then you'll get rid of 99.9999% of hackers.

**Fair warning:** I didn't do all of the above (just some) but I use the most important security rule of all: *Use common sense!*

Comment: Everyday is not sunday, It might not get 23 upvotes like previous similar question

Comment: I think It was simple for some one to tell me to check  /var/log/auth.log  ... where I found some evidence for trying to access my machine from china

Comment: If any decent cracker would have cracked you machine, there would have been no way for you to find them back in any of your logs, as the first thing a cracker does is cover his/her/its tracks.  If you're looking for more information on how to interpret log files, [here's where you need to look](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles).

Comment: If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** of the left hand side of the answer now turning it into beautiful green. If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow... If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: @FatMind traces of a user in /var/log/auth.log are evidence of you NOT being hacked, not of someone hacking you. 1st thing I would do is remove the lines in there showing I was on your system.

Comment: @Fabby rkhunter ... it has so many false positives it is useless on its own. If you want protection with rkhunter you need to install 2 or more of those rootkit softwares and match the results.

Comment: @Rinzwind: I know...  This was at the time Paranoid Panda was installing it, so I have some knowledge...  **;-)**