# Incoming ssh connections blocked

Tags: 12.04, security, openssh

Hi some time back I asked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181217/precautions-during-ssh) question and made a lot of changes to secure my system. Now I need to make a dummy account and give ssh access of this account to a friend. But I am unable to receive any incoming ssh connections. I can ssh to any server via my computer but can not ssh to even localhost. I am sure its due to some settings I changed in a bid to make my system more secure but know I don't remember those changes.

For one, I have disabled ufw. Also there is nothing blocking any user in /etc/ssh/sshd_config or in /etc/hosts.allow or /etc/hosts.deny.

I have attached the output of `ssh -v localhost` [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5999237/). I narrowed down the problem to `debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received` by comparing my output with [this output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5999243/) on a friend's computer.

Edit 1: This is the [output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5999539/) on using `ssh -vvvvvv localhost`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try re-installing sshd with a purge:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ssh-server
sudo apt-get install ssh-server
```

The most probable root cause is a botched config in /etc/ssh/ssh_config. A purge would remove this file, and give you a blank slate, hopefully fixing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue - secured system and unable to connect with a new account. It even seems to disconnect my existing connections with a different account, after a log in attempt.

I just found out that I restricted all access to only a few configured users.
The configuration is found in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
[..]
# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes
AllowUsers username1 username2
PermitEmptyPasswords no
[..]
```

I only need to add the username to the "AllowUsers" rule and restart the sshd daemon.