# Command to monitor all commands entered

Tags: command-line, 16.04, monitoring

Is there a command to monitor all commands, more along the side of remote access than the keyboard.I have experienced a problem in which the current version of firefox the bookmarks where removed so I am expecting a possible hack. Perhaps something like a trace.

Comment: Something like [htop](http://hisham.hm/htop/)?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean terminal (shell) commands? There is a `history` command which will print out the past commands executed. Provided the list is not cleared of course.

If you mean remote commands executed over ssh, take a look at the [first answer for this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3850/how-can-i-audit-users-and-access-attempts-to-ssh-on-my-server)